# How to extract text from a 'span' with more than on property using Python and lxml

Tags: python, matplotlib, lxml

I Have a problem while trying to extract some text from a span element using Python and lxml, I have managed this to work for some sites but not all. 
So i have a function that will extract the price from an site, this worked when using the URL and xpath in the following code snippet.

```cs
def get_price(last_date):
    page = requests.get('https://www.komplett.no/product/954922/gaming/gaming-utstyr/gamingskjermer/hp-omen-27-gamingskjerm-z4d33aa')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="product-price-now"]/text()')
    currentPrice = 0
    for string in prices:
        currentPrice = string.strip(",-")
        print(currentPrice)
    foo(currentPrice, last_date)
```

But when i tried to same method using a different URL and a different span element with more than one property, this wouldn't work, here is the code snippet of the span element i cant get the text of using

```html
<span class="DFlfde SwHCTb" data-precision="2" data-value="77954.88534">77,954.89</span>
```

Then i tried to extract the text from this span element by doing the following:

```
prices = tree.xpath('//span[@class="DFlfde SwHCTb"]/text()')
```

But that didn't work, any idea why`?

Comment: That span has a totally different class. It has `DFlfde SwHCTb` but your XPath looks for `product-price-now`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Hey, thanks for the input, i had changed the class name but i didn't implement that here, sorry for the misunderstanding, i have changed the post so it's a little more clear, thanks ^^

Comment: What's the other url?

Comment: @JackFleeting This is the other url: https://www.google.com/search?q=bitcoin+price&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNO862NO862&oq=bit&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2j69i60j69i61.1234j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8